# Creating a nested table

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a row of values that I partition into a table.

```
row = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};
rowPartitioned = Partition[row, 6]
```

> `{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}}`

Now I want to partition again to get the result

> `{{1, 2}, {7, 8}, {3, 4}, {9, 10}, {5, 6}, {11, 12}}`

How could I do the second partitioning?

Another example :

Starting with the 210 value row, with values 1 to 210, the output nested table would have 6 columns and 35 rows:
(1-6) (31-36) (61-66) (91-96) (121-126) (151-156) (181-186) (7-12) (37-42) (67-72) (97-102) (127-132) (157-162) (187-192) (13-18) (43-48) (73-78) (103-108) (133-138) (163-168) (193-198) (19-24) (49-54) (79-84) (109-114) (139-144) (169-174) (199-204) (25-30) (55-60) (85-90) (115-120) (145-150) (175-180) (205-210)

Comment: `Partition[row, 2][[Riffle[Range[1, 3], Range[4, 6]]]]`?

Comment: The first partition increased the depth while the second didn't, what is the rule? Please do not delete question if you want to edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this provide what you're looking for?

```
matrix = Flatten[Transpose[Partition[#, 6] & /@ Partition[Range[210], 30]], 1]
```

If you want it to display as a table, you can use:

```
matrix//MatrixForm
```

The first row `matrix[[1]]` gives `{1,2,3,4,5,6}`, the second `matrix[[2]]` gives `{31,32,33,34,35,36}`, and the first column `matrix[[All, 1]]` gives `{1,31,61,91,121,151,181,7,37,67,97,127,157,187,13,43,73,103,133,163,193,19,49,79,109,139,169,199,25,55,85,115,145,175,205}`.

Comment: Thanks, that works great!

Comment: @JamieM No problem, I'm glad it works!

Comment: If the resultant matrix has row1: XXYY, row2: AABB, row3: WWEE, row4: TTGG, how could that be further nested to give row1: XX, row2: AA, row3: WW, row4: TT, row5: YY, row6: BB, row7: EE, row8: GG.

Comment: @JamieM The first things that come to mind are `Join[mat[[All, 1;;2]], mat[[All, 3;;4]]]` or `Flatten[Transpose[Partition[#, 2]&/@mat], 1]` where `mat` is just your values above.

Comment: Thanks, creating 5-nested (or more) tables now with that.

Answer (score 1):

```
Riffle @@ (Partition[#, 2] & /@ rowPartitioned)
```

which gives output:

> {{1, 2}, {7, 8}, {3, 4}, {9, 10}, {5, 6}, {11, 12}}

Is that what you mean?

Comment: Hi, yes.  I am trying to get a general solution for larger rows, for example, the row of values 1 to 210 (210 values).  First partitioning that into 7 equal parts (1 to 30),(31 to 60),..(181 to 210).  Then partition each of those 30 value rows into 5 equal parts, each 6 columns by 5 rows, and join all the data so the final nested table result would have 6 columns and 35 rows.  The final nested table first column values are: 1,31,61,91,121,151,181,7,37,67,97,127,157,187,13,43,73,103,133,163,193,19,49,79,109,139,169,199,25,55,85,115,145,175,205.